Multiples of a number modulo another
A friend sent me these notes, which contain a reference for the result that the set of natural numbers of the form
$a+b \mathbb{Z}$ modulo $n$ where $a,b,n\in\mathbb{N}$ is equal to the set of natural number of the form $c+gk$ for $k\in\Big\{0,1,\ldots,\frac{n}{g}-1\Big\}$ where $g=\gcd(b,n)$ and $c=a \text{ mod } g$.
I'd be interested to know if there exists some other reference like a textbook or research paper published in a journal for this result. When I studied linear arithmetic I did not have this as a usual property. Also, the proof does not seem to be trivial

@BillDubuque thanks, please note the reference request tag

Duplicate surely (but may not be easy to locate). Here is a hint: with $,\color{#c00}{g := \gcd(b,n)},$ by Bezout, we have  $(a+b\Bbb Z)+n\Bbb Z = a+(\color{#c00}b\Bbb Z+\color{#c00}n\Bbb Z)= a+\color{#c00}g\Bbb Z = a\bmod g + g\Bbb Z.\ $  Are you familiar with cosets and quotient rings or groups?
